# Using the built in dynamic values

Tags: paw-app

I have written an extension to generate a custom authentication string (getting it to actually work would improve our team's performance significantly).

The issue: our custom authentication string requires a `HMAC` to be computed, which also requires an `MD5` hash. I tried requiring modules in a Nodejs fashion but it does not work. I noticed that the `HMAC` and `MD5` functions I need are already built-in in the application.

The question: Is there any way to re-use the built in functions in custom extensions? - Having this possibility would make the whole process so much easier.

If the above is not possible; how could I do something like: `var crypto = require('crypto');` in order to use Nodejs' default cryptography module?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there's a way to create and compute dynamic values from the JavaScript code, but it isn't documented yet. Here are the 2 functions you need implemented using dynamic values:

```
function hmac(key, input){
  return DynamicValue('com.luckymarmot.HMACDynamicValue', {
    algorithm: 0, // for HMAC-MD5
    input: input,
    key: key
  }).getEvaluatedString();
};

function md5(input){
  return DynamicValue('com.luckymarmot.HashDynamicValue', {
    hashType: 2, // for MD5
    input: input
  }).getEvaluatedString();
};
```

And and example of use in a custom dynamic value:

```
function evaluate(context){
  var a = md5("MyStringToHash");
  var b = hmac("MyHMACKey", "String to sign");
  return a + ':' + b;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Micha, almost but not quite. In the `md5` function, the `uppercase` property triggers an error: `JavaScript extension error: Invalid input <false>`

Another thing; I notice the `HMAC` encodes the response to `base64` by default. Do you plan on adding an option to select the output encoding? - In my case, I would need `hex` for example.

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to help @Aichholzer. I think you are running an older version of Paw, and `uppercase` has been added recently (in v2.2.3, 2.2.4 or maybe 2.2.5 I think). Also, yes, the next version is bringing this encoding parameter, with either Base64 or Hexadecimal. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using version 2.2.6 yet the `uppercase` issue still remains. I will be looking forward to that release with the optional output encoding. Thank you.

Comment: @Aichholzer sorry for late, you're very right, this is broken even in this app due to a bug in the JavaScript API when setting booleans, I'm working on a fix and will be shipped in the next bugfix version. In the meantime, I removed `uppercase` from my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I managed to decode the `base64` and re-encode it to `hex`, this is not the cleanest way of doing this, but until extra features are made available this might help people with similar issues. The `AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue` function can be adjusted to do whatever you need it to do.

```
(function() {

var request,
    url,
    md5 = function (input) {
        return DynamicValue('com.luckymarmot.HashDynamicValue', {
            hashType: 2,
            input: input
        }).getEvaluatedString();
    },
    hmac = function (key, input) {
        return DynamicValue('com.luckymarmot.HMACDynamicValue', {
            algorithm: 3,
            input: input,
            key: key
        }).getEvaluatedString();
    },
    base64Decode = function (input) {
        var a,
            b = 0,
            c,
            e = {},
            loop = 0,
            result = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            e['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'.charAt(i)] = i;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
            c = e[input.charAt(x)];
            b = (b << 6) + c;
            loop += 6;

            while (loop >= 8) {
                (( a = (b >>> (loop -= 8)) &0xff ) || ( x < (input.length - 2))) && ( result += String.fromCharCode(a));
            }
        }

        return result;
    },
    recode = function (input) {

        var decodedString = base64Decode(input),
            recodedString = '';

        // Encode binary to hex
        for (var i = 0; i < decodedString.length; i++) {
            var hex = decodedString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
            recodedString += ('000' + hex).slice(-2);
        }

        return recodedString;
    },
    AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue = function () {
        this.computeString = function (context) {
            request = context.getCurrentRequest();
            url = request.getUrl(true).components[1];

            var time = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000),
                md5Checksum = md5(request.jsonBody ? JSON.stringify(request.jsonBody) : url),
                signature = hmac(this.secretKey, md5Checksum);

            return recode(signature);
        };

        this.evaluate = function(context) {
            if (this.secretKey) {
                return this.computeString(context);
            }
        };

        this.title = function() {
            return "Authentication header";
        };

        this.text = function() {
            return;
        };
    };

AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue.identifier = "com.test.PawExtensions.AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue";
AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue.title = "AuthenticationHeader";
AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue.inputs = [
    DynamicValueInput("publicKey", "Public key", "String"),
    DynamicValueInput("secretKey", "Secret key", "String")
];

registerDynamicValueClass(AuthenticationHeaderDynamicValue);

}).call(this);
```